# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'formset' referenced before assignment in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hey so I have this list of campaigns that have a button to start and stop the process.

'''

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Campaign
from .forms import CampaignForm, CampaignStatusFormSet

def home_view(request):
    queryset = Campaign.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_type = request.POST.get('id')
        if form_type == 'campaign_status':
            formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(
                request.POST, request.FILES,
                queryset=queryset,
            )
            for form in formset.forms:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
    else:
        formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset, formset))

    context = {
        'formset': formset,
        'campaigns_and_forms': campaigns_and_forms,
    }

    return render(request, 'campaigns_in_progress.html', context)
```

'''

But when I run it and click on the button to change play/pause it shows this error.

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'formset' referenced before assignment**

Can anyone help me refactor this code so that it doesn't show this error?

Comment: If request.method is "POST" and form_type is not equal to "campaign_status", then the `formset` variable is never created.  You need to decide how to handle that case.

Comment: @JohnGordon do you have any ideas based on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right solution and if it won't break something else but for now it works perfectly. I just declared the formset before the if statement so it kind of declares 2 times.

If anyone could tell me if this is a good solution I would be greatful

'''

```
def home_view(request):
    queryset = Campaign.objects.all()

    formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(
        request.POST, request.FILES,
        queryset=queryset,
    )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_type = request.POST.get('id')
        if form_type == 'campaign_status':
            formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(
                request.POST, request.FILES,
                queryset=queryset,
            )
            for form in formset.forms:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
    else:
        formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset, formset))

    context = {
        'formset': formset,
        'campaigns_and_forms': campaigns_and_forms,
    }

    return render(request, 'campaigns_in_progress.html', context)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the else block so that the formset is available even after clicking on the play/pause buttons. When you send a POST request, and campaign_status is as expected, formset variable is not available in the `conext` and hence the error.

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from .models import Campaign
  from .forms import CampaignForm, CampaignStatusFormSet
  
  def home_view(request):
      queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
  
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form_type = request.POST.get('id')
          if form_type == 'campaign_status':
              formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(
                  request.POST, request.FILES,
                  queryset=queryset,
              )
              for form in formset.forms:
                  if form.is_valid():
                      form.save()
            # Set form with new created campaign         
            queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
            formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset=queryset)

            campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset, formset))

            context = {
                'formset': formset,
                'campaigns_and_forms': campaigns_and_forms,
            }

      else:
        formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset=queryset)
        campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset, formset))

        context = {
            'formset': formset,
            'campaigns_and_forms': campaigns_and_forms,
        }

    return render(request, 'campaigns_in_progress.html', context)
```

Comment: the problem with that solution is that now everytime i try to change start/pause it goes back to its default value so it never actualy changes

Comment: Okay, then you can make another query and pass a new formset when a campaign is created

Comment: I have updated the code, you can check it. The problem is you will be making two queries